# Recreating Mindstorms TRACK3R test track

Tags: mindstorms

I didn't realize until now that the 31313 Mindstorms packaging secretly contains a hidden test track for the TRACK3R robot. And the packaging is long gone with the trash. D'oh!

[image]

What is the simplest way of recreating the track so that it gets fully functional? Any web site where a blueprint can be found? What are the dimensions?

I have access to a color printer, color crayons etc.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For 15 bucks you can just buy the empty box on BrickLink. Here is [where you can get it](http://www.bricklink.com/v2/catalog/catalogitem.page?O=31313-1#T=S&O=%7B%7D). I think it would be a better use of your time to fork over the 15 USD (plus a few dollars shipping) than to try and recreate the test track. Here is why:

a. the test track is made of a durable cardboard which can withstand an ev3 unit driving over it. Normal paper will likely tear, especially since the test track is shiny and smoother than normal paper. It would be difficult for rubber tires or treads to turn on standard paper.

b. You would have to find the correct size of paper, or worse, connect smaller papers to recreate the track. Of course, it wouldn't have to be perfect, but it does add an extra step.

c. You would have to spend the time coloring. It doesn't sound that bad, but you would need to be very consistent with coloring sections so that the 'color' sensor doesn't have any problems reading the test track.

In short, I think it would be much easier for you to just buy the box rather than try to recreate it.

HOWEVER

If you do want to try to recreate it, BrickLink lists the box as having the dimensions 48 x 37.8 x 7.1 cm. Since the box folds out, the surface area of the box will be the dimensions of the test track. (48 + 2(7.1)) x (37.8 + 2(7.1))= 62.2 cm x 52 cm.
 The rest would just be a matter of coloring it based on the images.

I hope that helps you out :)

Comment: If I try to print and source the colors from online pics... how picky is the color sensor? Must the colors be exactly right or could it be off a little?

Comment: As long as you're not running out of toner/ink and are printing good quality images, you should be totally fine. Just make sure that coloration is consistent and dark (this only matters if you're not going to print it, and you plan on coloring it in).

Comment: The link the the Bricklink seller will probably not be around on the Internet as long as this answer. I would suggest updating to a more generic link that will still be relevant a year or more from now.

Comment: Your comment has been noted, and an edit has been made accordingly.

Answer (score 5):

Luckily I still kept the original packaging so I managed to open up the sleeve and take a picture.

[image]

The best photo I managed to take had some inconsistent lighting due to the flash and room lighting and the perspective wasn't the best so I decided it would be best to re-draw the board in Adobe Illustrator.

I deliberately didn't include some of the design elements that I didn't think were necessary. The original size was approximately 48 x 90 cm, these are the measurements I used for the Illustration.

[image]

You can print the above raster image or **[download the .SVG file](http://svgshare.com/i/Uz.svg)**. If you have access to a vector editor (Inkscape, for example, is free) you can re-adjust any of the elements however you like to better suite your needs.

If you don't have access to a large scale printer, I highly recommend you use the web service [Rasterbator](https://rasterbator.net/) which converts large images into smaller pages that can be printed using smaller paper sizes such as A4.

Rasterbator has several additional features, allowing you to adjust the margins to allow you to overlap pages, giving you a neat finish. Finally, glue the pages onto a piece of cardboard or craft card to add rigidity.

Comment: You're a savior! I find it strange that Lego doesn't offer this as a PDF (and also excludes it from [the list of items in the 31313 set](https://www.lego.com/en-us/mindstorms/products/mindstorms-ev3-31313)) but thanks to your very impressive effort that's less of a problem now. To make sure that the dimensions get right when printing, could you please publish the measurements of the original?

Comment: Sure. The dimensions are approximately 48 x 90cm.

Answer (score 2):

It turns out a workaround for the problem was to contact LEGO customer support and explain the situation. They swiftly sent me an empty 31313 box, delivered to my doorstep by courier.

You really can't ask for better customer support than that!