# What kind of mat do you use for running Mindstorm EV3?

Tags: ev3

Turning EV3 precisely has been a problem. Do you use a certain mat for running EV3 on? Can you tell me what material I need to get the mat printed?

Comment: There is not enough information here to answer your question. Can you be more specific? What does your robot look like? What are your tires? What are you trying to accomplish? What have you already tried?

Answer (score 2):

Mats are sometimes used with Mindstorms to create line following bots or for defining more complex tasks.

I can't give great advice on printing a mat for EV3, as I've never done this, but I would imagine that you'd want to be able to print on a large, fairly stiff piece of paper or cardboard. If you're just trying to create a basic line for your robot to follow, you can use a piece of posterboard and then add a line with black tape, markers, paint, etc.

There are several different mats that LEGO has made available for Mindstorms over the years:

https://www.bricklink.com/catalogList.asp?pg=1&catString=246&catType=P&v=1

I believe the most recent is actually the box sleeve in the EV3 kit:

[image: ev3sleeve]

You might want to just purchase one of the officially released mats.

Comment: If you are unable to purchase one of these mats or would like to redesign it as you wish, I have created [a replica of this mat](https://bricks.stackexchange.com/a/8349/132).